# Changing table column width using Google-Slide-API and python

Tags: python-3.x, google-slides-api

I have a Spreadsheet document and by using Google-Sheet-API I'm fetching the data from it. Then by using Google-Slide-API I'm creating a Slide document with 'n' slides. On each slide I'm creating a 2-column table with 'n' rows. Every first column on every slide always contains data from the Spreadsheet's A column. The second columns contain data from the other Spreadsheet's columns (from B to 'n'). Then I'm changing the text size. So far so good.

Now, when I try to adjust the columns width of each table on each slide it doesn't do anything which is an issue because some tables contain more information and therefore the tables don't fit the slide. This is the part of the code that doesn't work:

```
for i in range(number_of_slides):
    regs = [
        {'updateTableColumnProperties': {
            'objectId': tableID[i],
            'columnIndices': [j],
            'tableColumnProperties': {
            'columnWidth': {'magnitude': mag[j], 'unit': 'PT'}
                },
            'fields': 'columnWidth'
            }
         } for j in range(2) ]
     SLIDES.presentations().batchUpdate(body={'requests': reqs},
            presentationId=deckID).execute()
```

The tables always remain the same with or without this part so it doesn't have any affect whatsoever. The code doesn't return any errors or messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You have a Google Slides.
- The Google Slides has the several slides, each slide has a table which has 2 columns.
- You want to change the column width of 2 columns.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to use the batchUpdate method using Google Slides API.

#### Modification points:

- I think that your request body is correct. But, I would like to propose one modification point. In your script, `batchUpdate` method is used in a loop. I think that when  `batchUpdate` is used, `updateTableColumnProperties` for all slides in a Google Slides can be run by one API call.

Although I'm not sure about your values of `mag` and your whole script, as a sample script for achieving your above goal, how about the following modified script? If this helped you to understand Slides API, I'm glad.

#### Modified script:

About `creds`, please use your authorization script. Also, you can see it at [Quickstart for python](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/python).

```
service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)
PRESENTATION_ID = '###' # Please set Google Slides ID.
magnitude = [100, 300] # Please set the widths for the columns A and B in each table. In this sample, 100 and 300 PT are set.

# 1. Retrieve an object for each slides.
presentation = service.presentations().get(presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID).execute()

# 2. Create a request body for the batchUpdate method.
slides = presentation.get('slides')
requests = []
for slide in slides:
    pe = slide.get('pageElements')
    if pe:
        for pageElement in pe:
            t = pageElement.get('table')
            if t:
                for i, m in enumerate(magnitude):
                    requests.append({
                        'updateTableColumnProperties': {
                            'objectId': pageElement['objectId'],
                            'columnIndices': [i],
                            'tableColumnProperties': {
                                'columnWidth': {'magnitude': m, 'unit': 'PT'}
                            },
                            'fields': 'columnWidth'
                        }
                    })

# 3. Request the request body.
service.presentations().batchUpdate(body={'requests': requests}, presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID).execute()
```

#### Note:

- When above script is run, the widths of columns "A" and "B" of the table in each slide are modified. In this sample script, 100 and 300 PT are set for the columns "A" and "B", respectively. About this, please modify for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)
- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTableColumnPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablecolumnpropertiesrequest)

Comment: When I adapted your script to fit my script, it worked. Thank you very much! Your code is very helpful and it helped me to understand Slides API a little more.

Comment: May I have an additional question? Is there a way to change the padding using googleapi for python? I couldn't find this option in the Slides API documentation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Martin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My apologies, I will create a new question with detailed information. Again, thank you very much for your support, much appreciated.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for replying. When I found your new question, I would like to support you and think of the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your willingness to help, it is much appreciated. Luckily I was able to think of my own solution before posting a new question. My solution might not be ideal but I think it's the best way to learn. (I don't know if I should still post it because it might help someone else)
But when I get stuck on something else I will create a new question. It is good to know that someone gots my back. Again, thank you so much, you've been most helpful.